# Powershell regex, selection until specific string

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm not really goot at regex and tried for days to find the right powershell regex for the following situation:
Assuming I have the following input file:
`/export/home/ blabla1
blabla2`
`/export/home/ blabla3
blabla4`
`/export/home/ blabla5
blabla6`
I need a powershell regex expression that separates the selection including /export/home/ until the next /export/home/ appears.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean with '..separates the selection.." ???

Comment: I mean that i like to select everything including /export/home/ until the next /export/home appears. I used to use get-content but it's possible that there are several line breaks until the next /export/home/ appears. As far as i know get-content selects every single line. I would need multiple lines (depending on when /export/home/ shows up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do what you're trying to accomplish is doing a `-split` with a zero-length delimiter:

```
(Get-Content .\file.txt -Raw) -split "(?!^)(?=/export/home/)"
```

The right-hand argument basically says "split when":

```
(?!^) # not at start of string
(?=/export/home/) # next match is /export/home/
```

You can remove trailing newlines with `TrimEnd()`:

```
$Delimiter = '/export/home/'
$Escaped   = [regex]::Escape($Delimiter)
$Split     = "(?!^)(?=$Escaped)"
$Result    = (Get-Content .\file.txt -Raw) -split $Split |ForEach-Object { $_.TrimEnd() }
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that's exactly what I need :)